# Make the array received from server into a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question may look stupid, but the situation is this:

```
var element=[];
fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => element=data)
```

The data comes as an array. If i set it the above way, returns a single array. If i make it `element[0]=data`, it works but nest the arrays like this when logging `[[data]]`. If i make it `element=[data]`, returns empty array again. So what's the method to make the element into the array which contains the data i received? So it will look like this when logging: `[data]`

Comment: Can you provide an example of data you receive from server ?

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nev": "Feladatlista",
        "tipus": "a",
        "allapot": "letezo",
        "rang": 0,
        "szid": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nev": "asdasd",
        "tipus": "a",
        "allapot": "letezo",
        "rang": 0,
        "szid": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nev": "harmadik",
        "tipus": "a",
        "allapot": "letezo",
        "rang": 0,
        "szid": 2
    }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, here are the two possibilities of what i understood :

```js
let data = [ { "id": 1, "nev": "Feladatlista", "tipus": "a", "allapot": "letezo", "rang": 0, "szid": 0 }, { "id": 2, "nev": "asdasd", "tipus": "a", "allapot": "letezo", "rang": 0, "szid": 1 }, { "id": 3, "nev": "harmadik", "tipus": "a", "allapot": "letezo", "rang": 0, "szid": 2 } ] 

const element = []
 element.push(data);
// Should give you [[{} , {}]]
console.log(element);

 const element2 = [...data]
// Should give you [ {}, {} ]
console.log(element2)
```

Since this is an asynchronous call

```js
var element = []
fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => {
    element = [...data] .  // or element.push(...data) or element = data
    // Should give [data] 
    consle.log(element)
})

    // Should give [] : empty array since fetch is a promise 
    consle.log(element)
```

Comment: I need to define the variable outside the fetch. I need the same variable you defined as `data`, but i need to pass the data i received from the server to the outside variable, then export the variable. It don't work the way you shown.